# Что является аналогом DllMain в Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, разделяемые-библиотеки

Функция DllMain является дополнительной точкой входа в динамически подключаемую библиотеку.

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  __in  DWORD fdwReason,
  __in  LPVOID lpvReserved
);
```

Каким образом можно в linux задать код, который будет подобным образом выполняться при загрузке и выгрузке разделяемой библиотеки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задать код, который будет выполняться при подключении и отключении библиотеки, можно, используя атрибуты gcc `constructor` и `destructor`.

```
void start() __attribute__ ((constructor));
void finish() __attribute__ ((destructor));

void start() { // Выполнить до }
void finish() { // Выполнить после }
```