# Как выполнить функцию перед вызовом JNI_Onload?

Tags: jni, java, ubuntu

Java-приложение использует библиотеку на С. Целевая платформа - убунту 32 бита. Если упрощенно, есть три функции

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    // Делаем все, что обычно делается в JNI_Onload

    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}

jstring Java_com_example_self_Self_Hello(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello");
}

void InitializeBefore {
    // Должно быть выполнено до JNI_Onload
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы InitializeBefore была вызвана еще до вызова JNI_OnLoad. Это возможно? Если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попытаться использовать [конструктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-dllmain-%D0%B2-linux) для .so-шника. Но вообще, не совсем понятно, почему нельзя просто вызвать InitializeBefore в начале OnLoad.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 2):

Точный ответ на ваш вопрос не знаю, но как-то сам мучился с использованием native функций в Java. Помню, JNI показался мне неоправданно сложным и я начал поиск, который привел мення к JNA. Библиотека Java Native Access намного проще в использовании, чем JNI, но почему-то мало кто о ней знает. Советую обратить на нее внимание.

Comment: спасибо, буду иметь в виду

Answer (score 0):

```
class HelloWorld {
     private native void print();
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new HelloWorld().print();
     }
     static {
         // тут можно вызвать что то свое в ява коде перед загрузкой
         System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld"); // при загрузке класса HelloWorld загрузится HelloWorld.so
         // тут вызываем что то свое сразу после загрузки
     }
 }
```

Если вы хотите вызвать сишную функу в сишной библиотеке - вызовите ее прямо в сишной JNI_OnLoad.

Могут возникнуть трудности если вы в своей сишной InitializeBefore вызываете яву. незнаю - не проверял. Присоединяюсь к предыдущим авторам ответов, хотя про библу JNA не слышал - спасибо за информацию.

Кроме технических трудностей я одного не нашел во взаимодеиствии явы и с - как динамически загружать и ВЫГРУЖАТЬ библиотеки. Возможно это связанно с тем что не все платформы на которые портируется ява (и jni) могут это делать. хотя практически не пойму зачем это надо (если у вас новые библиотеки которые вы по сигналу перечитываете, мы такое у себя делали, то у вас нормальный с/с++ проект которому ява не нужна).